# Moment of Inertia of a Tilted Ring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

> A thin ring of mass M=4kg and radius, R=1m. Find its moment of inertia about an axis passing through its centre which makes an angle of exactly 45 degrees with the normal of the plane containing the ring.

I can’t develop a decent approach for this problem.....Would be really thankful if someone can guide me

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).